# H2 multiple network interfaces

Tags: java, h2

How does H2 deal with multiple network interfaces?
Currently I disable having two ips on one computer with the function getOwnIpAddress which returns an error message if two interfaces with an IP are found.

```
private String getOwnIpAddress()
    {
        ArrayList<String> ipAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            /*find out my own ip address*/
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces;
            networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(networkInterfaces))
            {
                Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
                for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses))
                {
                    if (isIPAddress(inetAddress.getHostAddress())
                            && !inetAddress.getHostAddress().equals("127.0.0.1"))
                    {
                        ipAddresses.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ipAddresses.size() > 1)
            {
                DialogMessage.showMessage(null, Resource.getResourceString("tooManyInterfacesError"), "",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                Main.quit();
            }
            else if (ipAddresses.size() > 0)
            {
                return ipAddresses.get(0);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can I let H2 prefer one IP? or can both be dealt by H2 in auto_server mode?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but did you try the system property `h2.bindAddress`? See also [the javadocs](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/SysProperties.html#h2.bindAddress).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the system property [`h2.bindAddress`](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/SysProperties.html#h2.bindAddress).

Comment: In my case I would use h2.bindAddress="localhost" because I use auto_server mode so that specific server IP is transparent to my program. I can't however understand how would H2 behave in this case of a Lan and a Wan interface, would H2 be smart enough to use the faster Lan interface? I'll be testing this but some official documentation or elaboration on the subject would be extremely interesting. Thank you